# How can I get the content of a Button in HTML with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Here is the html code :

```html
<button type="button" class="ncss-btn-primary-dark btn-lg" data-qa="notify-me-cta">Me prévenir</button>
```

and here is my python code :

```html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.nike.com/fr/launch/t/air-jordan-12-black-concord1'
content = requests.get(url)
html = BeautifulSoup(content.text, 'html.parser')

my_button = html.find_all("button", {"class": "ncss-col-sm-12 mt9-sm"})


print(my_button)
```

and this happen on the console :

[]

I don't know why this is not working.

Comment: You are trying to find a button with a different class. Wouldn't it be `ncss-btn-primary-dark btn-lg`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your button class is wrong
2. The page is loaded dynamically, so u have to use `selenium`

Here is the full code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time

url = 'https://www.nike.com/fr/launch/t/air-jordan-12-black-concord1'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(3)

html = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

my_button = html.find_all("button", {"class": "ncss-btn-primary-dark btn-lg"})

print(my_button)

driver.close()
```

Comment: Merci beaucoup !